# salamande(?): name of bread

Tags: baking, bread, cake, food-identification

Last weekend, I had a delicious bread, whose name was Sal-ra-man-d. Since English is not my native language, its name was written in non-english. It sounds like french. But I don't know its exact name. It is somewhat like a pound cake, with some cheese flavor. I think it is made of cream cheese. Is here anyone who knows its origin, or its original name. It is very hard to google what this bread really is.

[image]

Comment: Could you include the Korean name of the pastry (in Hangul)?  I took my best guess (살라만ㄷ) and Google Translate told me it meant *Salamanca* - although I see that Salamanca should really be written 살라망카, so maybe Google Translate doesn't know what it's talking about.  If it is meant to be Salamanca, maybe there's a pastry called Salamanca (though I've never heard of it), or maybe it's just someone's idea of a pastry eaten in Spain.

Comment: "cream cheese bread" doesn't tend to be an English thing ... I'd say it's probably from a Slavic or Scandinavian area, but I'm just finding a lot of recipes for "cream cheese bread" (eg, https://www.thekitchn.com/recipe-cheese-danish-bread-breakfast-recipes-from-the-kitchn-162823 ) without what the name is in its original language.

Comment: @Juhasz As you said, its Korean name is 살라망드(your guess is nearly perfect, notice that a Korean letter must contains at least one vowel). But only Korean bakeries has this name of bread and it is little weird to me.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that ㄷ looked wrong on its own.  I like Joe's idea about something Scandinavian.  I don't know enough about those cuisines to wager a guess, though.

Comment: @Juhasz I'm Scandinavian, and that doesn't look or sound Scandinavian to me.  Cream cheese is also not a Scandi thing, although there's a wide range of not entirely dissimilar dairy products like quark.

Comment: Note page 24 of [this Korean baking magazine](http://akmb.or.kr/jbcgi/board/masterbaker/MasterBaker_24.pdf), dating from 2015; it gives a recipe for a cherry 샬라망드 (note the very slight difference in hangeul spelling) - it seems very much like a cream cheese cake.

Comment: Is this it?  It's tough to tell what the topping is from your picture...

https://www.spain-recipes.com/orange-cake.html

Comment: it looks a lot like a cotton cheesecake. I found a blog discussing it, salamande bread... https://undodoc.com/12

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Korean blog post](https://undodoc.com/12) it is *Salamande* bread, and the packaging calls it "Taste of Europe". You know Koreans love a good European bakery.

[image: salamande bread inside]

[image: salamande packaging]

Salamande is also covered in [this blog post](https://ppoda.tistory.com/781) as well.

[image: salamande]

[image: inside salamande]

Comment: It seems the name is invented in Korea, because there is no post on Salamande outside Korea. Don't you think it is very strange.